# Jech *Set Theory* Lemma 14.18 proof

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Lemma $14.18$ in Jech's *Set Theory* states the following when expositing forcing.

> If $W$ is a set of pair wise disjoint elements of a Boolean algebra $B$ and if $a_u$, $u\in W$, are elements of $V^B$, then there exists some $a\in V^B$ such that $u\leq ||a=a_u||$.

I have a question about the first line of the proof.

> Proof: Let $D = \bigcup_{u\in W}\text{dom}(a_u)$, and for every $t\in D$, let $a(t) = \sum\{u\cdot a_u(t):u\in W\}$.

It seems like $a(t)$ isn't necessarily defined.  For example there may be some $t\in \text{dom}(a_u)$ and $t\notin \text{dom}(a_v)$ for $u,v\in W.$  Thus $a_v(t)$ is undefined. What is happening here?

Comment: (And in fact, the asker of that question mentions your exact question in a comment there as having the same issue.)

Comment: Okay, I'll close this question.  I'll keep it just because it mentions the Lemma number while the other one doesn't so if anyone searches it they will find this